# showing error like this Plug-in "org.eclipse.m2e.editor" was unable to instantiate class "org.eclipse.m2e.editor.pom.MavenPomEditor"

Tags: pom.xml

It showing error like this (Plug-in "org.eclipse.m2e.editor" was unable to instantiate class "org.eclipse.m2e.editor.pom.MavenPomEditor"). when selected POM.XML on maven project

I have try to run the maven project but not able to run it and that was happen only on maven java project not an java project. I want to run the maven project without any error so can you help me out on it.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to go to
help > Install New Software
work with: snapshots - http://download.eclipse.org/tm4e/snapshots/

And then select the "TextMate" component. Finish.
This installs the TM4E feature, which is used by the new pom editor to do syntax highlighting of the pom XML file.

The underlying reason for this issue is that the installation of the Spring Tools 4 components cause newer versions of TM4E to be installed with the exception of the bundle org.eclipse.tm4e.languageconfiguration, which remains installed in an older version that is no longer compatible with the newer org.eclipse.tm4e.ui bundle.

The installation of the feature (as described above) installs a set of TM4E components that all fit together again.

Update: you can also try to download eclipse again Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java and Web Developers from https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/
This time your issue would be resolved.

Comment: The solution of user26277 seems more robust since it does not rely on snapshot software. But thanks for pointing the cause !

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem with recent update of Eclipse 2023-06

Unable to open POM files with the usual POM editor.

the advice of Chandana_Akriti solved my problem. (Thanks !)

I rather installed the latest release version of t4me
from URL: https://download.eclipse.org/tm4e/releases/latest

- Textmate Core
- Textmate Language Pack

Note the the stacktrace was:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench 4 0 2023-08-10 15:55:29.644 
!MESSAGE IllegalThreadStateException 
!STACK 0 
java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException 
 at java.base/java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:1567) 
 at org.eclipse.tm4e.core.model.TMModel.startTokenizerThread(TMModel.java:249)
...
 at org.eclipse.m2e.editor.pom.MavenPomEditor.dispose(MavenPomEditor.java:730)
...
```

Hope this helps people having same problem.

Comment: Thanks, worked for me. The "usual POM Editor" is called "Maven POM Editor" for my install, BTW.